# Testing a 24V motor - Can I simply connect posts to a 12v battery?

Tags: dc-motor, solenoid, testing

I need to test if a 24V motor works or not. How can I test this just to make sure it functions? Is it possible to simply connect a 12V battery to the 2 motor posts and see if it spins, then reverse the Red/Black and see if it spins the opposite direction?

The system seems to be hooked up to a 12V battery with 4 solenoids, what I assume is some type of H Bridge to produce 24 volts for the DC motor. There is an issue somewhere I need to diagnose fully (Checking Motor Resistance, Switch, 4 solenoids, wiring, etc.), but at the core I need to just test quickly to rule out if the motor is bad or if it works at the simplest level.

Can I disconnect the wiring to the H-Bridge, and simply put 12V Red/Black to the motor posts and then reverse the order to see if the motor spins (Half speed) in both directions as expected?  Can I check the resistance between the 2 terminals without knowing the motor specs, since the motor details are unknown at this time?

Later I have much more diagnosis to be done, but I need to just check the motor works in both directions for now with only a 12V battery.

**EDIT:** The motor on this unit ended up being a 12V motor, as I was told it was 24V, but that was incorrect. I didn't have the product in my possession so I couldn't check, but I've come to find it is a 12V setup with 4 solenoids in an H-Bridge configuration.  A fresh battery solved the issue so I didn't have to do much diagnosis after all.

Comment: yes, the motor may spin ... difficult to say for sure ... a 24 V motor requires two 12 V batteries

Comment: `some type of H Bridge to produce 24 volts` ... the H bridge would supply 12 V to a motor

Comment: @jsotola, this has 4 separate solenoids, and the motor spins both forward and reverse. I was thinking maybe it is somehow up volting with the 4 solenoids vs 2, but maybe I'm wrong. My electrical knowledge comes and goes as I am involved in projects, then away for them for many months or years so my guesses are not always accurate. I'm hoping to just confirm the motor is good and spins vs dead, so hoping 1-12V battery will do that enough to tell.

Comment: @jsotola `24 V motor requires two 12 V batteries` to achieve *what*? I'd be surprised if a brushed DC motor didn't spin up at half nominal voltage. I wouldn't if an EC motor with UV lockout didn't move. `H bridge would supply 12 V to a motor` assuming duty cycle 50%?

Comment: I don't see how to have 4 devices with two terminals each in an *H-Bridge configuration*.